# Как получить индексы последнего элемента вложенного массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy

Есть вложенный массив, глубина вложенности зарание неизвестна. Например, пусть будет:

```
a=array([[[36, 30, 94],
    [76, 37, 72],
    [83, 74, 52]],

   [[49, 19, 34],
    [66, 52, 43],
    [42, 28, 86]],

   [[95,  5, 54],
    [27,  8, 81],
    [92, 36, 38]]])
```

Как можно получить индексы последнего элемента самого последнего вложенного массива?

В данном примере этот элемент – 38.

Comment: Вопрос к автору: Вы знаете, что такое индексы?

Comment: @V-Mor индекс - символ, указывающий место элемента в множестве

Comment: прошу прощения за такой глупый вопрос. Не сразу понял Вашу формулировку *В данном примере это 38*. Сначала показалось, что Вы имеете в виду, что в данном примере нужный индекс 38.

Comment: @V-Mor да ничего, бывает) А вы знаете как решить данный вопрос? Есть идея реверсировать матрицу и тем самым достучаться до первого массива, но потом не понятно как дойти до неизвестной глубины

Comment: как вариант – проверять тип элемента, и если это `list`, "копать" глубже, а если уже `int`, значит глубина найдена. А потом с известной глубиной уже в бой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы получить последний элемент матрицы любой размерности (число столбцов и число осей/размерностей заранее неизвестно):

```
last = a.ravel()[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Последний индекс элемента массива = -1. А размерность массива может узнать из a.shape

```
>>> a.shape
(3, 3, 3)
```

т.е. при обращении

```
>>> a[-1,-1,-1]
38
```

ну или из a.shape вычесть 1 ( np.array(a.shape)-1 )

```
>>> a[a.shape[0]-1,a.shape[1]-1,a.shape[2]-1]
38
```